# How to create a separate List of Appendices like List of Figures or List of Tables in Lyx

Tags: lyx, lists, appendices

My university requires a separate "List of Appendices" to be placed after the List of Tables and List of Figures in the dissertation.

I created an Appendix from a normal chapter with Document->Start Appendix Here

At PDF generation the Appendix appears in TOC as "A  
instead Appendix A , however I could not find an easy command like the Insert->List/TOC->List of Figures for the Appendices.

I would like to accomplish two things:

1. Create a separate List of Appendices to be placed after the List of Figures
2. If possible to remove the Appendix A entry from TOC

First item is the most important as I can live with the entry in the TOC although it looks ugly.

Is there an easy way to do this in Lyx or at least a latex command that would construct the List of appendices that I can place after the List of Figures?

EDIT: I ended up doing it manually since I have only one Appendix, and it looks fine, but it dose not have the clickable hyperlink as the other lists. I have to figure out that one too.

Comment: If you know how insert an ERT box or how edit  the LaTeX preamble in LyX, then this is a duplicate of  [List of Appendices](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/list-of-appendices?rq=1).

Comment: @Fran What exactly to enter in the ERT box? The code you are referring to is specific to the class that particular individual is using, which does not apply in my case.  I need a code that does not rely on a specific university class, which for obvious reasons I cannot use. And yes, I know how to edit the preamble and how to enter an ERT box.

Comment: Exactly you must enter in ERT boxes the part that you can not  enter in the preamble. On the other hand, you do not give  information of your document class, so I can only guess if  the above link or [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9138/creating-a-separate-list-of-appendices-with-tocloft) or [some other](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124555/list-of-appendices-without-chapter-titles) can help.

Comment: @Fran. I saw that link you are referring to and I don't like the solution and it seems that it is not agreed upon may others too. I hoped that there is some code that works for any document class as the List of Figures seems to work. I give up I  do it manually for one Appendix it is not worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

[this answer is from here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113823/separate-list-of-appendices-in-new-page),
copy the following into your preable

```
\listfiles
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listofappendixname{Table of \appendixname}

\newcommand\listofappendices{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\listofappendixname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\listofappendixname}{\MakeUppercase\listofappendixname}}%
    \@starttoc{toa}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\appendixname}%
  \xpatchcmd{\@part}{\addcontentsline{toc}}{\addcontentsline{toa}}{}{}%
  \xpatchcmd{\@part}{\addcontentsline{toc}}{\addcontentsline{toa}}{}{}%
  \xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{\addcontentsline{toc}}{\addcontentsline{toa}}{}{}%
  \xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{\addcontentsline{toc}}{\addcontentsline{toa}}{}{}%
  \xpatchcmd{\@sect}{\addcontentsline{toc}}{\addcontentsline{toa}}{}{}%
  \xpatchcmd{\@sect}{\addcontentsline{toc}}{\addcontentsline{toa}}{}{}%
}
\makeatother
```

Then where you want to add the list add the `\listofappendices` in ERT

don't forget to make with `\appendix` command in ERT at the body of the text the area you want as an appendix.

Comment: No, it is not. \appendix just marks that the following text is an appendix

Comment: I have edited my answer, in case you haven't read the link I added in the beginning of the answer

Comment: @Elan Den I will try you solution and let you know what happens

Comment: @Bogdan any update? Did it work?

Comment: No, it did not, but I did not try too hard. I gave up on it and I added just the list of appendices manually. It was easier for me to add two lines than to go through all these complicated and unsupported procedures. Maybe next time when I have a longer list of appendices.

Comment: @Bogdan: `Not try too hard` is not really helpful

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I know, I usually try my best, but when you have time constraints sometimes you take the path that gives you faster the results you want. This is especially true when it is unlikely that you are going to use that technique again. I am past that, I hope someone who needs it can take it from here and improve on the matter.