# Indent appendices in table of contents, undo for Bibliography

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I'm using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64403/how-to-make-appendices-behave-like-sections-in-toc) to indent the chapters of my appendix as sections in the table of contents. Before my appendices, I added:

```
\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{\let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section}
\makeatother
```

So my body is:

```
\input{discussion/discussion}

\appendix
\begin{appendices}
\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{\let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section}
\makeatother
\input{appendix/walking-statistics}
\input{appendix/standing-statistics}
\end{appendices}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{bibliography/HRG}
```

This results in a TOC like:

```
5  Chapter
    5.1  Section 1
    5.2  Section 2
Appendices
    A  Lorem Ipsum
    B  Lorem Ipsum II
    Bibliography
```

However, I want to have my bibliography at the top level of the table of contents:

```
5  Chapter
    5.1  Section 1
    5.2  Section 2
Appendices
    A  Lorem Ipsum
    B  Lorem Ipsum II
Bibliography
```

But I can't figure out how to essentially "undo" the change in the way that chapters are organized in the table of contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `\addtocontents` command to

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\bgroup\let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section}
```

and add the following line at the end of your `appendices` environment:

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\egroup}
```

This delimits the effect of the `\let` statement to the area between `\bgroup` and `\egroup`.